# In a space faring egalitarian civilization where immortality is the norm, how would you enforce an upper limit on age by region?

Tags: immortality

The premise is a space faring civilization that achieved post scarcity and immortality but not enlightened enough to be immune to petty feelings like jealousy.

In this post scarcity civilization, the main currency is prestige and getting more prestige is the main reason humans who refused to indulge in VR paradise are still active.

Immortality is achieved through uploading your conscience into a new biological or cybernetic body (the details don’t matter but it could be something like the sleeves of Altered Carbon).

Because of immortality, established entities have such a head start over new entities that it is almost impossible for newcomers to do anything relevant and gain any prestige. This has caused some problems including wars that wasted energy and time.

The Federation strongly values Egalitarianism and agreed on a solution that seemed reasonable for everyone.

Systems at the edge of the federation would be reserved for new entities only. 
Entities above the age limit are not allowed to enter or trade with those regions. The penalty for breaking the rule is permanent deletion (real death).

How can I enforce that no one cheats?

Comment: If you haven't already read [Corey Doctorow's Down and Out in the Magic Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_and_Out_in_the_Magic_Kingdom), I strongly recommend it.  Very similar to the story you are creating.

Comment: You need to clarify how your "prestige" system operates.  I'm not at all clear why anyone want this ?  Is it money ?  Does it give extra authority ?  How exactly do you get it ?  Who decides you get it and how much you get ?  Just amassing lots of "prestige points" seems useless the entire population are super-egomaniacs or there is some advantage to having it.  The prestige system is the actual problem you have, but you haven't really defined that problem.

Comment: Imagine one of the twin made the kessel run at 0.999c and came back to marry the great great great great great great great great great great great grand children... which was born from an egg donated by their great great great great great great great great great great grandma. Actually sounds great.

Comment: I could write essays on this and still not have set up a fully viable system, one of the fundamental issues is that you've got it set up backwards.

Comment: This appears to be a clear victim of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). I would suggest reframing your question to ask about your problem, instead of your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that advanced technology is required for your immortality, your problem will solve itself.  In advanced technical civilizations, like those present among the inner planets, everything is digital.  Your wealth, your influence and your prestige are maintained and tracked by omnipresent super-secure computers.

Those computers can maintain the age barrier.   If an elder performs a prestige amplifying action on a planet with an age restriction, the computer grants no prestige points for that action.  It also contacts the police and disables all public facilities around the elder so that he cannot escape from capture.

The computers don't care about prestige, so nobody is rich enough to bribe their way past the computerized police and judges.  This is post scarcity.  Non-violent Crime is obsolete.  Bribery, influence peddling, theft and fraud are all relics of the past.  You do what the computers say you should, or you might as well leave reality behind via VR.

Since the only reason people leave VR is to gain prestige, and since the computers won't let an elder earn prestige on an age-limited planet, elders have not choice but to leave the inner planets.

They are free to stay and live in prestige-less poverty...  but why would they?

Answer (score 2):

Reputation is the key to access certain areas and privileges.

Reputation can be gained both through time and activities, resulting in upvotes and downvotes from the community. (*wait, where have I already heard about this?*)

Unlike here on SE, there are both maximum and minimum reputation thresholds to be allowed in certain areas or in doing specific activities, so that long established individuals with high reputation won't be hogging the tasks which for newcomers are the only completable ones.